# Is it possible to update a user's username using graph.microsoft.com?

Tags: graph, azure-ad-b2c

I am setting the username in Azure b2c equal to the users phone number. when the user changes their phone number, I would like to be able to do this by calling the Microsoft graph api. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Can you please share which attribute you are using? Is it done using `signInNames` collection? like `signInNames.userName`

Here are the list of attributes relevant to b2c: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes

You can view and update `SignInNames.userName` using Graph API. You can try it out using any HTTP tool like cURL, Postman or [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)
To view the userName for all users use the query:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=identities`

For a specific user run the query:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserObjectID/?$select=identities`

To update the userName, use `PATCH` operation which is going to update the userName using the Graph API for a specific user. You need to use user's object id as shown below:

PATCH: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/05b83c4a-8e1e-4197-93c4-aba90b7aac64/?$select=identities

```
{
"identities":
 [
  
 {
 
 "signInType":"userName",
 "issuer":"DOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com",
 "issuerAssignedId":"USER_NAME"

 }

]}
```

[image]

Also, curious why not use Phone based sign in? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-authentication

Comment: We are using signInNames.phoneNumber, can this be updated via Microsoft Graph? We are not using Phone based because we did not want passwordless login and require a text message to be sent each time the user has to log in.

Comment: Phone sign in does exactly what you’re describing. In regards to your question, PATCH the Identities object with your new value.  "identities": [
    {
      "signInType": "userName",
      "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "+4467568765"
    }]

Comment: Yes, you can update the value of signInNames attribute using Graph API as Jas alluded above. You can use Microsoft Graph Explorer (developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to test it out. I have updated  the answer with more detailed instructions.